# Why do I get symfony form error on non existing field?

Tags: forms, symfony

[image]

As we can see in the screenshot - there is error "Mailing Address not filled".

propertyPath ends with .zipcode.

How is this possible?

On the left we see mailing addres elements but non of them is zip code.

```
$user = $this->getUser();

    $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('required' => true))
        ->add(
            'mailingAddress',
            UserFormType::class,
            array(
                'check_modifiable' => true,
                'data' => $user,
                'form_parts' => 'mailing_address',
                'label' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'show_password' => false
            )
        );

    if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_CUSTOMER')) {
        $formBuilder
            ->add(
                'businessInformation',
                BusinessInformationType::class,
                array(
                    'check_modifiable' => true,
                    'data' => $user,
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                )
            );
    }

    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

In UserFormType there is this code which adds fields:

```
foreach ($this->userManager->getGroupPermissions($userGroup, $options['form_parts']) as $setting) {
            /** @var UserGroupPermission $setting */
            if (
                $setting->getIsActive() &&
                (
                    empty($options['show_only_parts']) ||
                    in_array($setting->getFieldName(), $options['show_only_parts'])
                )
            ) {
                $this->addFormFieldBySetting($builder, $options, $setting);
            }
        }
```

I have debugged, it does not add zipCode field.

In template:

```
{% block zip_code %}                    
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4">
                        {% if form.mailingAddress.zipCode is defined %}
                            {{ form_row(form.mailingAddress.zipCode,{
                                'attr': {
                                    'data-mask': '99999',
                                    'data-rule-zipcodeUS': 'true'
                                }
                            }) }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    {% endblock %}
```

again debugged - `form.mailingAddress.zipCode` is not defined and so field is not rendered.

User.php entity also does not have a minimum lenght requirement:

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zip_code", type="string", length=16, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(max="16")
     */
    protected $zipCode;
```

How to debug this? I tried stepping thought those vendor files but they make tons of steps I get validation error but did not notice where it actually adds it exactly so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what is causing:

In the $errors cause object we see constraint. Had to look at this constraint. For some reason first time when I checked that constraint - it did not cause violation.

Answer (score 0):

First, even if the field is nullable into ORM declaration, you must set it as required false in the form (this not automatic).

Second, are you sure that zipCode is defined into UserFormType ?

Third, this is strange that your mailing address is a UserFormType (probably namig error).

Comment: I was sure zipCode was not defined in UserFormType. Just found out that validator was giving violation at path zipCode.

Comment: Ok, did your form works alone ? i.e 
$form = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user)->getForm();

Just to know if the problem come from FormType or its usage in another type.

Comment: I have no motivation to try, since not having problem anymore.